# Upload image to Cloudinary and generate a low-res version as a different URL at the same time

Tags: android, image, file-upload, thumbnails, cloudinary

I am using Cloudinary to upload pictures from Android, but since they are usually a bit large I would like to generate a thumbnail for it that has a different URL.

This will allow me to have a full-resolution and a low-resolution version but only uploading the large picture.

I know I can use eager transformations, but I couldn't find a way to also get a different URL for the transformed one.

The equivalent would be for me to upload the full-res version and then do a new upload with the eager transformation. But that would increase the amount of data transfer my Android app needs, for what is essentially the same information.

So instead of upload full-res->get url->upload low-res->get url, I want
full-res->get both urls

Is there any way I can upload only once and get two URLs for the different versions?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm struggling with uploading image to Cloudinary. It gives me `Unable to resolve host "api.cloudinary.com": No address associated with hostname` this error. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cloudinary's transformation string is included in the URL itself, the transformed image's URL is different than the original one.
For example:
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg
vs.:
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_200/sample.jpg

Comment: Yes, but that consumes a transformation each time the image is accessed if I understand correctly. Since the lowRes version will be used to display the list of photos, I can't spend 1 transformation for each photo query. Maybe I'm getting this wrong. Maybe the transformation is only spent the first time? I have found a solution that seems a bit hackish but worked.

Comment: Indeed a transformation is only counted once. After it is generated for the first time it is stored in your account for quicker recurring accesses. Re-requesting the same URL is only counted towards your 'Bandwidth' quotas.

Comment: I confirmed that indeed transformations are only counted the first time they are created. So to get the low res version I just used a transformation as suggested and everything else was solved. Thanks